# Facebook JS SDK: Tagging a friend in me/feed POST

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am developing a simple Facebook app which will basically just allow users to POST statuses, photos, etc. - this is just an exploratory project at the moment.

I have been trying to POST statuses with varying privacy levels and have been able to POST with custom privacy successfully, however, when I try to tag a friend in the POST headers I get an oAuth exception error response.

My scope appears to include everything necessary to do what I want, but I may be missing something here.

> "...&scope=email,user_groups,user_photos,read_friendlists,manage_friendlists,publish_stream,read_stream"

Here's my JS code:

```
FB.api(
                "/me/feed",
                "POST",
                {
                    "message": $('textarea').val(),
                    "tags": $('input').val(),
                    "privacy" : {'value': 'CUSTOM','allow': $friend_list.val() }
                },
                function (response) {
                  if (response && !response.error) {
                    console.log('response is: ');
                    console.log(response);
                  }
                  else{
                      console.log('oops something went wrong here!');
                      console.log(response);
                  }
                }
            );
```

As the SDK docs are not really that informative, I am not really sure what the purpose of place, which I apparently have to include:

> Comma-separated list of user IDs of people tagged in this post. You
>   cannot specify this field without also specifying a place.

I have tried setting "place" as a variety of values but I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. I have deliberately omitted it from the example code above by the way.

Thanks in advance

-- EDIT --

As requested, here is an example list of the headers being posted:

```
message:this is an example post
method:post
privacy:{"value":"CUSTOM","allow":"123456789012345"}
```

The above works correctly (given the correct user ID's that is), i.e. a status is created and it is only viewable by a single user/friend, but once I include "tags" it throws an oAuth error with little to no info or explanation. The reason I am trying to "tag" friends by the way is that I want people to be notified of a POST rather than just having access to it.

```
message:this is an example post
method:post
privacy:{"value":"CUSTOM","allow":"123456789012345"}
tags:123456789012345
```

I have also tried to set the "place" header, but again I have little understanding of its purpose so I may be supplying an incorrect value or something like that.

Comment: Can you give a full example of what you post. In your example you don't set post and you are not mentioning people you are setting the privacy so only some people can see the post

Comment: @WizKid thanks for your response, see the edit above for an example of the data I am sending. POSTing the first headers works, and the status is created but I am just trying to figure out why setting "tags" then causes an oAuth error.

Comment: So do you want to set the privacy or mention people? If you want to mention people you can only do that if you are at a place with some people and that is why you need to specify a place

Comment: I actually want to do both. The privacy would allow you to have a closed conversation without having to create a group or anything like that. But tagging users would send notifications, without having to include them within the message body itself. I know this probably seems illogical and it may even break the metaphor proposed by Facebook. Should I just include users in the message body? And if so, is there a straightforward way to do this using the SDK?

Comment: You are not allowed to write the message. The user have to. And you are only allowed to tag people if they are at the same location as the user posting.